# Elastic search Index creation via Highlevel Rest api fails?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-high-level-restclient

I am trying to run an embedded elastic search instance (6.6.10 . then after starting the embedded instance , i am trying to create an index with an index mapping . However i am getting the following exception.

```
ElasticsearchStatusException[Elasticsearch exception [type=illegal_argument_exception, reason=unknown setting [index.doc.properties.@timestamp.type] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings]]
    at org.elasticsearch.rest.BytesRestResponse.errorFromXContent(BytesRestResponse.java:177)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.parseEntity(RestHighLevelClient.java:2050)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.parseResponseException(RestHighLevelClient.java:2026)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.internalPerformRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1775)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1732)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequestAndParseEntity(RestHighLevelClient.java:1694)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.IndicesClient.create(IndicesClient.java:151)
    at com.openmind.primecast.web.rest.PerformanceReportingResourceIntTest.startElasticServer(PerformanceReportingResourceIntTest.java:121)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:541)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:763)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:209)
    Suppressed: org.elasticsearch.client.ResponseException: method [PUT], host [http://localhost:57457], URI [/mep-reports?master_timeout=30s&timeout=30s], status line [HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request]
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"unknown setting [index.doc.properties.@timestamp.type] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"unknown setting [index.doc.properties.@timestamp.type] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings","suppressed":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"unknown setting [index.doc.properties.@version.type] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings"},{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"unknown setting [index.doc.properties.account_id.type] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings"},{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"unknown setting [index.doc.properties.campaign_id.type] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings"},{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"unknown setting [index.doc.properties.campaign_name.type] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings"},{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"unknown setting [index.doc.properties.delivery_ts.format] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings"},{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"unknown setting [index.doc.properties.delivery_ts.type] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings"},{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"unknown setting [index.doc.properties.flight_id.type] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings"},{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"unknown setting [index.doc.properties.flight_name.type] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings"},{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"unknown setting [index.doc.properties.inventory.type] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings"},{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"unknown setting [index.doc.properties.msg_text.type] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings"},{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"unknown setting [index.doc.properties.nof_segments.type] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings"},{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"unknown setting [index.doc.properties.o_error.type] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings"},{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"unknown setting [index.doc.properties.recipient.type] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings"},{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"unknown setting [index.doc.properties.sender.type] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings"},{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"unknown setting [index.doc.properties.status.type] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings"},{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"unknown setting [index.doc.properties.submission_ts.format] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings"},{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"unknown setting [index.doc.properties.submission_ts.type] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings"}]},"status":400}
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient$SyncResponseListener.get(RestClient.java:929)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:229)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.internalPerformRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1762)
        ... 23 more
    Caused by: org.elasticsearch.client.ResponseException: method [PUT], host [http://localhost:57457], URI [/mep-reports?master_timeout=30s&timeout=30s], status line [HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request]
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"unknown setting [index.doc.properties.@timestamp.type] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"unknown setting [index.doc.properties.@timestamp.type] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings","suppressed":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"unknown setting [index.doc.properties.@version.type] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings"},{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"unknown setting [index.doc.properties.account_id.type] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings"},{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"unknown setting [index.doc.properties.campaign_id.type] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings"},{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"unknown setting [index.doc.properties.campaign_name.type] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings"},{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"unknown setting [index.doc.properties.delivery_ts.format] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings"},{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"unknown setting [index.doc.properties.delivery_ts.type] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings"},{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"unknown setting [index.doc.properties.flight_id.type] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings"},{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"unknown setting [index.doc.properties.flight_name.type] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings"},{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"unknown setting [index.doc.properties.inventory.type] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings"},{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"unknown setting [index.doc.properties.msg_text.type] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings"},{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"unknown setting [index.doc.properties.nof_segments.type] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings"},{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"unknown setting [index.doc.properties.o_error.type] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings"},{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"unknown setting [index.doc.properties.recipient.type] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings"},{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"unknown setting [index.doc.properties.sender.type] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings"},{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"unknown setting [index.doc.properties.status.type] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings"},{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"unknown setting [index.doc.properties.submission_ts.format] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings"},{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"unknown setting [index.doc.properties.submission_ts.type] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings"}]},"status":400}
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient$1.completed(RestClient.java:548)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient$1.completed(RestClient.java:533)
        at org.apache.http.concurrent.BasicFuture.completed(BasicFuture.java:123)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.DefaultClientExchangeHandlerImpl.responseCompleted(DefaultClientExchangeHandlerImpl.java:181)
        at org.apache.http.nio.protocol.HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.processResponse(HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.java:436)
        at org.apache.http.nio.protocol.HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.inputReady(HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.java:326)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.DefaultNHttpClientConnection.consumeInput(DefaultNHttpClientConnection.java:265)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalIODispatch.onInputReady(InternalIODispatch.java:81)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalIODispatch.onInputReady(InternalIODispatch.java:39)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIODispatch.inputReady(AbstractIODispatch.java:114)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.readable(BaseIOReactor.java:162)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvent(AbstractIOReactor.java:337)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvents(AbstractIOReactor.java:315)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:276)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:104)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:588)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

The following is the code snippet that use the java high level rest client.

```
CreateIndexRequest indexCreationRequest = new CreateIndexRequest("mep-reports"); 

indexCreationRequest.source(IOUtils.toByteArray(getJsonResourceAsStream()), XContentType.JSON);

CreateIndexResponse createIndexResponse = client.indices().create(indexCreationRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```

The following is the index mapping i am using. the index mapping is returned by getJsonResourceAsStream()

```
{"doc":{"properties":{"@timestamp":{"type":"date"},"@version":{"type":"text"},"account_id":{"type":"keyword"},"campaign_id":{"type":"keyword"},"delivery_ts":{"type":"date","format":"epoch_millis"},"submission_ts":{"type":"date","format":"epoch_millis"},"flight_id":{"type":"keyword"},"inventory":{"type":"keyword"},"msg_text":{"type":"keyword"},"nof_segments":{"type":"keyword"},"o_error":{"type":"keyword"},"recipient":{"type":"text"},"sender":{"type":"keyword"},"status":{"type":"text"},"campaign_name":{"type":"keyword"},"flight_name":{"type":"keyword"}}}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found the solution as my mapping document was incorrect format . it should be as follows.

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "doc": {
      "properties": {
        "@timestamp": {
          "type": "date"
        },
        "@version": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "account_id": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "campaign_id": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "delivery_ts": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "epoch_millis"
        },
        "submission_ts": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "epoch_millis"
        },
        "flight_id": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "inventory": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "msg_text": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "nof_segments": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "o_error": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "recipient": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "sender": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "status": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "campaign_name": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "flight_name": {
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```